# jquery dynamically change select option based on another select's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html select dropdowns:

```
<select name="county" id="county">
<option value="Any">Any County</option>
<option value="Lancaster County">Lancaster County, PA</option>
<option value="Berks County">Berks County, PA</option>
<option value="Montgomery County">Montgomery County, PA</option>
<option value="Dauphin County">Dauphin County, PA</option>
<option value="Adams County">Adams County, PA</option>
<option value="Chester County">Chester County, PA</option>
<option value="Lebanon County ">Lebanon County, PA</option>
<option value="Delaware County">Delaware County, PA</option>
<option value="York County">York County, PA</option>
<option value="New Castle County">New Castle County, DE</option>
<option value="Orange County">Orange County, NY</option>
</select>

<select name="township" id="township">
<option value="Any">Any Township</option>
<option value="Bethel Township">Bethel Township</option>
<option value="Borough of Cornwall">Borough of Cornwall</option>
<option value="Concord Township">Concord Township</option>
<option value="Cumberland Township">Cumberland Township</option>
<option value="Derry Township">Derry Township</option>
<option value="East Brandywine Township">East Brandywine Township</option>
<option value="East Hempfield Township">East Hempfield Township</option>
<option value="Kennett Township">Kennett Township</option>
<option value="Lower Merion Township">Lower Merion Township</option>
<option value="New Castle County">New Castle County</option>
<option value="Penn Township">Penn Township</option>
<option value="Springfield Township">Springfield Township</option>
<option value="Town of Warwick">Town of Warwick</option>
<option value="Township of Spring">Township of Spring</option>
<option value="Treddyfrin Township">Treddyfrin Township</option>
<option value="Warwick Township">Warwick Township</option>
<option value="West Bradford Township">West Bradford Township</option>
<option value="West Donegal Township">West Donegal Township</option>
<option value="West Lampeter Township">West Lampeter Township</option>
<option value="West Vincent Township">West Vincent Township</option>
<option value="West Whiteland Township">West Whiteland Township</option>
<option value="York Township">York Township</option>
</select>
```

I need a jquery script that does the following:

When a specific `#county option` is selected, only the appropriate `#township options` are displayed.  For example:

If the Lancaster County option is selected, only West Donegal Township, West Lampeter Township, East Hempfield Township, Warwick Township options will be displayed.

Or, if the Berks County option is selected, only Township of Spring will be displayed.

I've tried other examples of jquery code to make this function work and can't seem to get it to do what I need.  I have little knowledge of jquery/javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to post the javascript you've tried

Comment: Take a look at http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained it should work for you

Comment: What about using search function on this site?

Comment: @FreshPro I didn't forget, I specifically did not add any scripts. I'm looking for new scripts from anyone who can write something based on my specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it using classes and an extra select. The idea is to have a "pot" of townships to pull the data from when a county is selected.

You'll need to add a class to each option in the `county` select, and corresponding classes to the `pot` select options. For example, for Lancaster County, I've added the class `lancaster`, then on each of the `pot` options that you want to show up when Lancaster is selected, I've added the same class. I've done the first 3 for you in the code below:

HTML:

```
<select name="county" id="county">
    <option value="Any" class="any">Any County</option>
    <option value="Lancaster County" class="lancaster">Lancaster County, PA</option>
    <option value="Berks County" class="berks">Berks County, PA</option>
    <option value="Montgomery County">Montgomery County, PA</option>
    <option value="Dauphin County">Dauphin County, PA</option>
    <option value="Adams County">Adams County, PA</option>
    <option value="Chester County">Chester County, PA</option>
    <option value="Lebanon County ">Lebanon County, PA</option>
    <option value="Delaware County">Delaware County, PA</option>
    <option value="York County">York County, PA</option>
    <option value="New Castle County">New Castle County, DE</option>
    <option value="Orange County">Orange County, NY</option>
</select>

<select name="township" id="township">
    <option value="Any">Any Township</option>
</select>

<select id="pot">
    <option value="Any" class="any">Any Township</option>
    <option value="Bethel Township">Bethel Township</option>
    <option value="Borough of Cornwall">Borough of Cornwall</option>
    <option value="Concord Township">Concord Township</option>
    <option value="Cumberland Township">Cumberland Township</option>
    <option value="Derry Township">Derry Township</option>
    <option value="East Brandywine Township">East Brandywine Township</option>
    <option value="East Hempfield Township" class="lancaster">East Hempfield Township</option>
    <option value="Kennett Township">Kennett Township</option>
    <option value="Lower Merion Township">Lower Merion Township</option>
    <option value="New Castle County">New Castle County</option>
    <option value="Penn Township">Penn Township</option>
    <option value="Springfield Township" class="berks">Springfield Township</option>
    <option value="Town of Warwick">Town of Warwick</option>
    <option value="Township of Spring">Township of Spring</option>
    <option value="Treddyfrin Township">Treddyfrin Township</option>
    <option value="Warwick Township" class="lancater">Warwick Township</option>
    <option value="West Bradford Township">West Bradford Township</option>
    <option value="West Donegal Township" class="lancaster">West Donegal Township</option>
    <option value="West Lampeter Township" class="lancaster">West Lampeter Township</option>
    <option value="West Vincent Township">West Vincent Township</option>
    <option value="West Whiteland Township">West Whiteland Township</option>
    <option value="York Township">York Township</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('#county').change(function() {
    // get the class of the selected option
    var select_class = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
    // clone all options from the pot select
    var $options = $('#pot > option.'+select_class).clone();
    // delete all of the options in the township select and append
    // the new options
    $('#township')
        .find('option')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .append($options);
});
```

CSS:

```
select#pot {
    display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7X65/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is to understand how it is done.

First note that this type of functionality is called dependent dropdown/combo boxes or cascading dropdown/combo boxes.

Usual way of implementation will be that the dependent dropdown's data is fetched using jquery at run time from a source like via Ajax call to server, or a client side source like a Javascript map or array.

Understand that if we pick a value from the first combo-box, jquery will clean the options which are not required from the HTML unless we first store them first. Precisely the reason why we always fetch them rather take from HTML, so that option data is not lost.

Here's the code below and the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ZerL3/1/

Please note that I've also taken care of the un-select event or when you select "Any" from drop down, all options must be shown

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#county").change(function () {
    var comboMap={
        "Lancaster County":
          ["West Donegal Township",
             "West Lampeter Township"],
        "ABC County":
          [
             "PQR",
             "XYZ"
          ]};//keep adding to map here
        $('#township').empty();

        var county = $(this).val();

    var lcns = comboMap[county] || [];
    var html=[];
    if(lcns.length===0) {
         var lcnsAll=comboMap;
        $.each(lcnsAll,function(i,item){
            lcns=item; 
        html +=$.map(lcns, function(lcn){
            return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>';}).join('');

              });
               }
              else {
        html = $.map(lcns, function(lcn){
            return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>';
        }).join('');}
                  $('#township').html(html);
    });

    });
```

**PS:** Please observe that I had put the map(`comboMap`) inside the change function. This makes it transient and also unavailable outside the combo box. If your map is very large, it and privacy of the map is not an issue, you may consider putting it before change event (i.e. first thing unde ready function definition).